# How to Secure access to classes in my DLL only to my program?

Tags: c#

The executable file (.exe file) of my program is getting bigger as I keep adding more and more features. So, I would like to move some of the code/classes into library project (DLL file) and reference the DLL from my main program.

However, I don't want any other program to reference and use the classes and methods of my class. So, how can I protect the code in DLL so that only my program executable can access the code/classes inside DLL file?

Comment: Short answer: You can't.  Longer answer: It sounds like you want obfuscation, but that only makes it _hard_ to use, not impossible.

Comment: You can simply make it internal, then add InternalVisibleTo attribute, so without reflection it will be impossible to use something, but only without reflection.

Comment: Thanks guys, i will try this option out. will it be easy if I obfuscate the DLL?

Answer (score 1):

There are no easy way to do that, but may be you can use the **GenericIdentity** features to simulate your application as a user on whose behalf the code is running.

So, first in your EXE program, set a **Role Definition**, based on an unique string (a GUID for example).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Set a Role Definition
    GenericIdentity myIdentity = new GenericIdentity("MyIdentity");
    string[] myRoles = new string[] { "9d882dd6-22b8-4927-914c-911bbc824327" };
    GenericPrincipal myPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(myIdentity, myRoles);
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = myPrincipal;

    // Using the other DLL
    Assembly1.Class1 myClass1 = new Assembly1.Class1();
    myClass1.MyMethod1();

    // ...
}
```

And this code in your external DLL to check if this "user" has the correct "Role" (with the **PrincipalPermission** attribute).

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "9d882dd6-22b8-4927-914c-911bbc824327")]
public class Class1
{
    public void MyMethod1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyMethod1 started");
    }
}
```

If the main program don't define correctly the "User Role", you will receive a SecurityException (Request for principal permission failed).

Comment: Thanks Denis, looks to be good option. I will need to try it out in sample project and see how it works. I will share my experience once I try this out.

Comment: Looks to be a good option. So, if I comment the Set Role Definition lines, it  gives "Request for principle permission failed." error (see attached) which is good. And If I uncomment, the code works fine. I will further need to evaluate if the code really works if I obfuscate the DLL.

Comment: Yes, if you comment the Set Role Definition, you will received an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark you classes with `[StrongNameIndentityPermission]` attribute like described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa288522(v=VS.71).aspx). This will prevent access to your code even through Reflection for all unmatched assemblies.

Comment: Definitely your application should be Strongly Named for this to work

Comment: Starting with the .NET Framework 4, identity permissions are not used.
In the .NET Framework versions 1.0 and 1.1, identity permissions cannot have an Unrestricted permission state value. In the .NET Framework version 2.0 and later, identity permissions can have any permission state value. This means that in version 2.0 and later versions, identity permissions have the same behavior as permissions that implement the IUnrestrictedPermission interface. That is, a demand for an identity always succeeds, regardless of the identity of the assembly, if the assembly has been granted full trust.

Comment: Here is the reference link - [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.strongnameidentitypermission(v=vs.110).aspx)